# Routing not working the same on two internal NIC

Tags: networking, dhcp, netplan, domain-server

on mu Ubuntu 22.04 server I have two internal NIC and one external connected to the Internet.
I have defined the interfaces with Netplan as follows :

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 100
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.1/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 127.0.0.53
        - 8.8.8.8
        search:
        - wombats.org
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.254
        - to: 172.16.1.0/24
          via: 172.16.1.1
          metric: 200
          table: 101
      routing-policy:
        - from: 172.16.1.0/24
          table: 101
    wlp8s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
        - 172.16.2.1/24
      routes:
        - to: 172.16.2.0/24
          via: 172.16.2.1
          metric: 20
          table: 102
      routing-policy:
        - from: 172.16.2.0/24
          table: 102
  version: 2
```

A computer connected to enp2s0 is routed perfectly to the internet and internally. When the same computer is connected through wlp8s0 it cannot even reach the network managed by enp2s0 (172.16.1.1/24).
Here are the two routing tables :
connected through enp2s0 :

```
ip r
default via 172.16.1.1 dev enxf8e43b9d4867 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enxf8e43b9d4867 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.1.0/24 dev enxf8e43b9d4867 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.3 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

connected through wlp8s0:

```
ip r
default via 172.16.2.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
172.16.2.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.2.4 metric 600 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

The notable difference is the metric of the default route in both configurations. This does not come from the DHCP server as both subnets are configured identically. I have tried to disable ufw and tried to add iptables. But all that has not changed the result.

I do not understand why I cannot route the traffic of the wlp8s0 ! Does the fact that one NIC is a cable and the other a wifi explain the difference ? It should not as they get served IPs in the same way.

Thanks for your help.
Jan

Comment: I have found out that adding the following rule to /etc/ufw/before.rules : "-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.2.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE" at least allows me to reach the Internet from NIC wlp8s0. But I still cannot connect to the other network (172.16.1.0/24).

Comment: What I also noted is that for each interface defined in netland the option "ignore-carrier: true" is essential. It ensures that the NIC is defined even if no carrier is connected.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was twofold :
First the masquerading needs to be done on both interfaces (subnets) :

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.1.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.2.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Then what is not less important is that the interfaces are brought-up with or without carrier. This done in /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml with the line:

```
    enp2s0:
      ignore-carrier: true
```

same for the wlp8s0. If you do not